# Match/paste VBA using 2 sources

Tags: excel, vba

So my current code is below - this simply finds the value of "E1" on my source sheet - finds that value on the dest sheet then pastes the data from a set range undereneath the cells with that value.

However I would like to match a column and row for example:

I want to find the value of columns A:A in the source sheet - match this to the correct row in the dest sheet but also match this to the value of "E1" in the source sheet.

Does this make sense - please if you need more let me know - I'm new here.

```
 WkNo = Source.Range("E1").Value

 With Source
 Set rFndCell = Dest.Range("1:1").Find(WkNo, LookIn:=xlValues)
 fcol = rFndCell.Column

 Source.Range("B2:C10000").Copy
 Dest.Cells(3, fcol).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

**Source Sheet**

[image]

**Destination Sheet**

[image]

Comment: It would be difficult to find the value of column A:A -- how many values are there in column A? Do you want to find each value one at a time? When you find a value, what should be done then? If you match a value from column A to a correct row on another sheet, what should be copied and where should the data go? Perhaps provide an example of your data.

Comment: @PeterT there are 970 values in column A:A - i would like to match these values 1 at a time to column A:A in the dest sheet - then copy the data from column B & C to the correct valued row. However keeping the value of E1 as a variable at the same time.

Comment: You don't need VBA to do this, you can use the `VLOOKUP` formula. On the destination sheet, in cell D4 for example, use the formula `=VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$A:$C,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @PeterT That works great - however the whole reason for VBA is because I need to match the week number. If you look at the source sheet, you can see a 4 this is the current week number, this also needs to match the correct column in the source sheet - if you look at 1:1 it states 1 & 2, this goes on to week 53

Comment: Not trying to force you away from VBA (I'm constantly coding solutions in it myself), but you can still use a formula. On the destination sheet in cell D4 again, the formula would be `=IF(D$2=Sheet1!$E$1,VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet1!$A:$C,2,FALSE),"")`. Then just extend that formula out through your destination columns. It checks the value of the week number on top of the destination column and compares it to the week number on the source sheet in cell E1.

Comment: Thank you - If i was to put this in VBA - due to data being drawn daily. Would i loop this to next row? Or just record me dragging etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how to construct the VBA solution. It doesn't use formulas or copy-paste. To copy the values, it's a quick assignment from one cell to another.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyWeeklyValues()
    Dim weekNumber As Long
    weekNumber = Source.Range("E1").Value

    Dim fndCell As Range
    Set fndCell = Dest.Range("1:1").Find(weekNumber, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not fndCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim weekColumn As Long
        weekColumn = fndCell.Column

        '--- now loop over all the rows to copy the data
        '    to the correct row
        With Source
            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            Dim i As Long
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                Dim partNumber As String
                partNumber = .Cells(i, 1).Value

                Dim destPart As Range
                Set destPart = Dest.Range("A:A").Find(partNumber, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not destPart Is Nothing Then
                    destPart.Cells(1, weekColumn).Value = .Cells(i, 2)
                    destPart.Cells(1, weekColumn + 1).Value = .Cells(i, 3)
                Else
                    '--- what happens if you can't find the part number?
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Else
        '--- couldn't find the week number on the destination sheet
        '    do something about it?
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, for the loop I assume a simple end row with offset would be suitable?

Comment: That would work fine. My code above is an example for you to modify to fit your exact needs.

Comment: It seems where you have put to loop i dont actually need one - seems to work great. unless im missing something. Thank you so much!